# Find the area of triangle $QST$

Tags: triangles, problem-solving

In triangle $PQR$, $U$ is a point on $PR$, $S$ is a point on $PQ$, $T$ is a point on $QR$ with $US$ being parallel to $RQ$, and $UT$ is parallel to $PQ$.
The area of $PSU$ is $120 in^2$ and the area of triangle $TUR$ is $270 in^2$.
The area of $QST$ in $in^2$, is

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5tdx.png)

[image]

This is a multiple choice question

$A) 150$

$B) 160$

$C) 170$

$D) 180$

$E) 200$

I figure triangle $STU$ being equal to triangle $QST$ but $SU$ is not confirmed as equal to $QT$. Is there any way to confirm the lengths, maybe if I separate the areas of the two triangles to experiment with proportions since the two triangles with area have parallel sides equal to each other.

Comment: When $US \parallel RQ$ and $UT \parallel PQ$, $UTQS$ will be a parallelogram. This means $|SU| = |QT|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triangles $UTR$ and $PSU$ are both similar to triangle $PQR$, and thus to each other.  The ratio of their areas is $\frac{270}{120} = \frac94$, so the ratio of their bases $UR$ and $PU$ is $\sqrt{\frac94} = \frac32$.  Since $PR = PU + UR$, the ratio of $PR$ to $PU$ is $\frac52$.  Thus the area of triangle $PQR$ is $\frac{25}{4}$ times that of $PSU$: $\frac{25}{4}\cdot120 = 750$.  Subtracting the two smaller triangles from the total, the area of parallelogram $SQTU$ is $750 - 120 - 270 = 360$. The area of triangle $QST$ is half that of the parallelogram, $\frac12\cdot360 = 180$, which is choice $D$.